# Video and audio controls does not work in html

Tags: html, audio, video, html5-video, controls

If i use autoplay, the audio plays but then it does not stop on clicking the pause-play button. Similarly, i cant change the volume or mute the audio. My video doesnot play at all. Only the control bar is shown, nothing else happens. I use Chrome browser, just in case it has to do anything with that. I dont know whats wrong. Also is there any difference in HTML and HTML5 that may have something to do with the video tag?

```
<audio src="ACDC%20-%20Back%20In%20Black.mp3" controls autoplay></audio>

<video height="300px" width="300px" autoplay controls>
    <source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnZtdrcA4f8">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
 <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnZtdrcA4f8">
```

There is nothing wrong with audio code.
Try adding type to it `type="audio/mpeg"`

Comment: No, I am still facing exactly the same problems. It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have problems with both the video and audio tags. I have found that the only sure answer was to script in my own controls. The problem I have seems to relate to the window size and I will leave a full diagnosis to a real expert! Give your video or audio and id.

```
    <button onclick="y=document.getElementById('all');y.load();y.play();" type="button" >START></button>
```